# Insert brackets in a multiple set of data with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have this set of data in excel,

```
2006-12-29
2007-01-01
2007-01-02
2007-01-03
2007-01-04
2007-01-05
2007-01-08
2007-01-09
2007-01-10
2007-01-11
2007-01-12
```

etc.. (2612 rows of data)

I want to keep the date format CCYY/MM/DD and add brackets and the word "Money" to reach this outcome:

```
[CCYY/MM/DD] [Money],
[CCYY/MM/DD] [Money],
[CCYY/MM/DD] [Money],
```

I am using this code:

```
Sub addbrackets()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "DDL.PTBV"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        Rng.Value = "[" & Rng.Value & "]" & "[Money],"
    Next
End Sub
```

But it keeps me sending this [29/12/2006][Money], wrong date format..

Could someone help me?

ps: I have tried to change the format type in "2" (text) but it still does not work

Comment: use `format` round rng.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rng.Value = "[" & Format(Rng.Value, "YYYY/MM/DD") & "]" & "[Money],"
```

Answer (score 0):

First take the Data and replace "-" with "/".

```
string = replace(string, "-", "/")
```

Then assemble it:

```
string = "[" & string & "]" & "[Money],"
```

Now Loop at the data and edit one by one in the Loop ;) Hope this helps!